# repeated prints out

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have **reviews** objects which hold arrays of **reviews** and I am trying to printout(**po**) values on the console, the right hand side.

But everytime, it prints two times for the same object. I just wonder what is wrong?

**AppDelegate**

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) YLPClient *client;


@end

@implementation AppDelegate

+ (YLPClient *)sharedClient {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    return appDelegate.client;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [YLPClient authorizeWithAppId:@"VaD3dX7rhyfS_tVJKOu8pp" secret:@"YTCQCG3nCErq54oeXSJbYd5kEW9OrTKcEpG1e3BKBixNTS7US3LgDdg8QAW3tUXX" completionHandler:^(YLPClient *client, NSError *error) {
        self.client = client;
        if (!client) {
            NSLog(@"Authentication failed: %@", error);
        }
    }];
    return YES
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[AppDelegate sharedClient] reviewsForBusinessWithId:@"fadis-meyerland-mediterranean-grill-houston" completionHandler:^
         (YLPBusinessReviews *reviews, NSError* error) {
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             });
    }];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you paste you code?

Comment: The code is on the right hand side. `po [reviews.reviews objectAtIndex:2]`

Comment: [Edit] your question with your code that creates and populates the `reviews` variable.

Comment: I have added some code

Comment: But the code you posted isn't helpful. We need to see how `reviews` is created and populated.

Comment: it is getting reviews from YELP API.

Comment: I have also included more code.